# MIDI, how to get measures and notes

Tags: python, midi

Many MIDI libraries like [mido](https://pypi.org/project/mido/) and [pretty_midi](https://pypi.org/project/pretty_midi/) provide list of all messages in MIDI files. I am looking for a code to get the list of measures and all notes in each measure. Is there a specific library for calculating beats and measures (bars)?

Comment: What does "in a measure" mean? And what would you need this information for?

Comment: @CL.Actually, I need all notes in each measure. I want to calculate the note ranges in each measure for statistics purposes.

Comment: If you're happy with .NET too, you can use my library [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) that has all these high-level calculations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no library that does this for you.
You have to determine the length, in ticks, of each measure from the
[time signature meta event](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta_message_types.html#time-signature-0x58) (or event**s**, if the signature changes), and then compute from the timestamps of the note-on and note-off messages to which measure they belong. (The two messages might end up in different measures.)

Comment: Maybe it would be better to write "There is no library for Python"? :) Since with [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) (.NET library) it's easy to solve the task.